# Is it a good idea to create Java game server using SOAP Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, multiplayer

so I need to create a java game server and I'm looking for good tools to do it.

I'm also pretty much familiar with CXF Web Services technologies
and i was wondering if I could use it to create a server for a multiplayer game where
I will probably need to manager game sessions and other "multiplayer game" stuffs, or maybe web services are not adapted for that?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget the client side which may not like heavy protocol overhead: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/answer/REST-or-SOAP-Which-offers-the-most-benefits-for-mobile-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. But if you want to provide an easy to use API, perhaps REST would be a better architecture, since it's much easier to write a REST client. Today, I would only recommend SOAP Web Services as an integration solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great platforms out there that provide a full range of backend services for games. It will save you a lot of time and headache :)

E.g take a look at [Parse](https://parse.com/)